# network restart fail on Ubuntu server 16.04

Tags: networking, server, 16.04, systemd

In Ubuntu 16.04 server I want to change IP from /etc/network/interfaces and run `sudo service networking restart` and there is no error given but the IP didn't change.

I also ran `sudo systemctl networking restart` and `sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0` but the IP doesn't change.
How do I restart the network interface in Ubuntu 16.04 so it saves the changes?

Comment: I think you're on a normal home-network. Those use usually the Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol (DHCP). If the DHCP-Server doesn't assign that IP to you, you won't get that IP (no matter what you configure on /etc/networking/interfaces). Worse, you could even get no net at all, if you misconfigured.

Comment: @ManuToMatic I need to set static IP on interface!

Comment: Yes, and in the DHCP-Server too. If your server says "Yo, I'm configured to use `192.0.0.42` so give it to me!" but your DHCP (Router/Modem) answers "Yeah, nice. But I only distribute `192.168.0.2` to `192.168.0.50` so you get that nice `192.168.0.31`", then your server gets `192.168.0.31` and not the IP he wants. If you want more information about how DHCP works: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol

Comment: @ManuToMatic I don't have any DHCP server in my network and need set static IP

Comment: What? So how is your network configured? Believe me, if you didn't do anything special, your router IS a DHCP-Server.

Alternatively you could explain exactly how your network is set up so we'd know more specific what we're on.

Comment: I need to set static IP and change IP work properly in Ubuntu14.04. I need set static IP On Ubuntu Server 16.04. I cant setup DHCP server in my network.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a bug in Ubuntu network scripts.

If you will modify network interface and then do the `ifdown` it will fail. You must first bring the interface down. Then you can modify the file and then bring the interface up again:

```
$ ifdown eth0
$ $EDITOR /etc/network/interfaces
$ ifup eth0
```

Comment: It seems to be a bug, but sometimes ubuntu needs to be restarted

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to restart anything. Using Network Manager (i.e. click on the network icon), disconnect the interface, and then click on it to reconnect. You should see the new IP on the interface.

In general, it's good to remember that if Network Manager is running, it expects to be managing interfaces. Attempting to change interfaces with cli commands will usually result in network manager changing them back, or something similar/worse. If you don't want Network Manager to manage an interface, simply delete the interface from Network Manager.